# Doctrine Entity extending another Entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Hi I read this article http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html yet I'm not quiet sure how to accomplish the following:

I have a "user"-Table, a "man"-Table and a "woman"-table.
I want my php classes `Man` and `Woman` extend the `User` Object.

Annotationmapping:

```
    namespace Core\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * User
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="user", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="email_UNIQUE", columns={"email"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="username_UNIQUE", columns={"username"})})
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class User
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        private $firstName;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="middle_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        private $middleName;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        private $lastName;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
         */
        private $username;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
         */
        private $email;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
         */
        private $password;

        /**
         * @var \DateTime
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
         */
        private $createdAt;

        /**
         * @var \DateTime
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
         */
        private $updatedAt;

        /**
         * @var \DateTime
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="last_login", type="datetime", nullable=false)
         */
        private $lastLogin;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="login_hash", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        private $loginHash;

        /**
         * @var boolean
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="is_premium", type="boolean", nullable=false)
         */
        private $isPremium = '0';

        /**
         * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Core\Entity\Bill", inversedBy="user")
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_has_bill",
         *   joinColumns={
         *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         *   },
         *   inverseJoinColumns={
         *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bill_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         *   }
         * )
         */
        private $bill;

        /**
         * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Core\Entity\Picture", inversedBy="user")
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_has_picture",
         *   joinColumns={
         *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         *   },
         *   inverseJoinColumns={
         *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="picture_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         *   }
         * )
         */
        private $picture;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->bill = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
            $this->picture = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        }

    }
```

Woman:

```
namespace Core\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Woman
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="woman", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_woman_user1_idx", columns={"user_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Woman
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Core\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Core\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Core\Entity\Cart", inversedBy="woman")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="woman_has_cart",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="woman_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cart_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $cart;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Core\Entity\Interest", inversedBy="woman")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="woman_has_interest",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="woman_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="interest_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $interest;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Core\Entity\Man", inversedBy="woman")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="woman_has_man",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="woman_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="man_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $man;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cart = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->interest = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->man = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

}
```

The man mapping looks (for now) the same as the woman.

Here a little Snippet from MysqlWorkbench http://s14.directupload.net/images/131013/fbg7okyn.png

The basic idea is this:

Men and Women share some common logic and individual logic. For example take a login. Men and Women need an email and a password to log in. Since it's redundant to implement the same login logic twice I thought of creating a more abstract class, the `User`, which is where I want to put everything which applies to men and women, like name, email, password, login logic etc...

This is where it gets tricky with doctrine. Men and women will have individual fields to store in the database, yet they still need their "common data"(name, password etc...), so a simple `class Man extends User` might not work out correctly. I store the corresponding id of the `User` on men and women. So there is an identification.

What I had in mind is, if I do `$men->getPassword()` it should use the `getPassword()`function of the corresponding `User` object.

I hope I cleared up my intend.

Kind Regards and thank you for digging through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have done this what you're looking for in one of my projects once, It's done not too good code wise, but the mapping is fine ;) Please check [this link](https://github.com/manuakasam/SamMarketplaceCategoryBehavior/tree/master/src/SamMarketplaceCategoryBehavior/Entity)

- Item.php.dist would be your User Entity
- (Property|Vehicle).php.dist would be your Man / Women Entity
- Please notice that the Property Discriminator Mapping is missing within the code examples. I do it differently in the application ;)

Ultimately you wouldn't want to have separate "Tables" on your SQL Server. It all belongs to the Superclass "User" and therefore belongs to the User-Table. You will extends the UserTable and use DiscriminatorMapping to map specific entities.

Note: A Man can not be editted to become a Woman! You'd have to kill the man and give birth to a woman :P

Imagina this Model:

```
User
  *id
  -name
  -surname

Man extends User
  -pc_power

Woman extends User
  -nail_color
```

Your DB-Schema would look like this:

```
Table User:
  *id (pk)
  -discriminator (not nullable) (value: man or woman)
  -name (not nullable)
  -surname (not nullable)
  -pc_power (nullable as far as DB is concerned)
  -nail_color (nullable as far as DB is concerned)
```

You do not need 3 tables to mod your models like this. It makes literally no sense to do this. It just slows your Queries down by quite a bit.

Now a Dataset could look like this:

```
A Man: (1, man, john, doe, 4ghz, null)
A Woman: (2, woman, john, doe, null, pink)
```

Now on Doctrines side of things you do Queries against the USER-Entity

```
$entity = $userRepository->find(1);
echo get_class($entity); // returns "Man"

$entity = $userRepository->find(2);
echo get_class($entity); // returns "Woman"
```

Does that make things more clear, because otherwise i'm simply unable to help you :P

Comment: hi sam, i learned a lot of zf2 from your page. But back to topic. Since men and women need to login i thought a "user" with all the elemental fields like email, password etc... would be fine and since men and women are treated seperatly i wanted to devide that logic than put everything on the user. On your github I dont think i need the interfaces, but it seems since i put a seperate id on `woman` and `men` the mapping will break. Would a MySqlWorkbench model help?

Comment: You maybe have to explain your actual problem further. Ultimately my Entity "Item" equals your "User" and both "Property" and "Vehicle" equal your "Man" and "Woman". Logic/Data for both go onto User and Logic/Data for Men/Woman go into their respective entities

Comment: @Soundz The Workbench pic is kinda "useless" - you'd just have a field "is_man" or "is_woman" which is true / false. If you need shared logic, i can only urge you to try to understand the Code i have provided you. It does exactly what you want. But it uses a different DB-Schema. Do not go DB-Schema first. Doctrine follows the Model-First principle. To me it appears that you don't understand the inheritance-mapping of doctrine :S

Comment: thats true, its not quiet clear. but just to make it clear: You understood my approach with shared and individual logic? - OK. But if i got you correct, I cant convert that approach in doctrine the way I intended it. I know doctrine follows Model-First, but it's easier for me planning my initial db layout a bit more visual.

Comment: @Soundz Please see my edit, if that doesn't help, i can't help :D